# Format string attack - jump to shell on x64

Tags: c, linux, security, exploit, shellcode

How to exploit `printf` format string vulnurability on 64 bit system with NX enabled?

In this code example, what could you do to get a shell?

```
void f(char *buf) {
  printf(buf);
  exit(0);
}

int main() {
  char buf[1024];
  scanf("%1024s", buf);
  f(buf);
  return 0;
}
```

I think that because of NX and lack of obvious place to jump (there is no `execve(/bin/bash...` anywhere in the code) it has to be a return-to-libc attack, but where to jump?

I belive it is possible to overwrite GOT entry of `exit` to jump to arbitrary location, for example `execve` or `system`, but how to set proper arguments in registers? Search the binary for ROP chain and jump there?

Or is there some other way to get a shell out of this?

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Format_string_attack

Answer (score 0):

On top of all you've said yourself, nowadays most `printf` functions don't support the `%n` marker used to exploit format strings, so that attack technique is kind of dead.

It might very well be unexploitable in today's scene. So unless this is a exercise in format string exploitation or a capture the flag type of thing I suggest you focus on more up-to-date exploitation techniques.